# User input to query statement

Tags: php, html, sql-server

I am attempting writing a script in PHP to accept user input from my HTML to query and output all data with the input.

I have written the parts to display the information and output the results.
I have no idea were to start on replacing the query information with the user input.

```
<?php  
 $serverName = "server"; //serverName\instanceName

 $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"", "UID"=>"", "PWD"=>"");
 
 $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
 
 $query = "SELECT DISTINCT 
    r.[offense_id]
    ,r.[department_id]
    ,r.[report_id]
    ,r.[reporting_event_number]as 'Case Number'
    ,r.[record_number]
    ,[offense_code_name]
    ,[nibrs_code]
    ,[nibrs_code_name] as 'Crime'
    ,[nibrs_group_name]
    ,[offense_classification] as 'Crime Literal'
    ,[offense_location_full_address]
    ,[offense_location_subdivision_1] as ZONE
    ,[offense_location_subdivision_2] as BEAT
    ,[offense_location_category]
    ,[offense_location_additional_description]
    ,[offense_created_date]
    ,[offense_updated_date]
    ,[report_created_date]
    ,[report_case_status] as 'Case Status'


    FROM [DEPT_15139205077].[analytics_rms].[vw_report_offenses] r
    INNER JOIN [DEPT_15139205077].[analytics_rms].[vw_report_event_infos] e ON r.report_id = e.report_id
    LEFT JOIN [DEPT_15139205077].[analytics_rms].[vw_report_narratives] n ON r.report_id = n.report_id
    LEFT JOIN [DEPT_15139205077].[analytics_rms].[vw_cases] c on c.case_number = r.reporting_event_number
 
    WHERE report_created_date BETWEEN GETDATE()-7 AND GETDATE()  
    AND [nibrs_code] IN ('09A','09B','11A','11B','120','13A','220','23A',
            '23B','23C','23D','23E','23F','23G','23H','240')"; 
             
 $result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query);  

 ?>
```

Need the report created date to change based on user input

Comment: SQL Parameters.